# send jwt token from react webpage to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm using jwt token for user authentication on my website, so once a user logs in, I store the token in localStorage, and I want to have the token on my chrome extension, such that the user is also authenticated while using the extension.

I've tried passing the token using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` on the react side and `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` on the chrome side to connect them but that didn't work.

In the manifest.json I have specified the extension to communicate with my website

```
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/"]
  }
```

```
// example from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('I'm here');
    if (sender.url == blocklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      console.log(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

I think the message is not sent because I didn't see anything in the console, and I get an error in the chrome extension saying "Uncaught Error: extension.sendRequest, extension.onRequest, and extension.onRequestExternal are deprecated. Please use runtime.sendMessage, runtime.onMessage, and runtime.onMessageExternal instead." But I'm already using the suggested ones.

I've also tried to use the `chrome.storage.sync.get` method to access the localStorage from the extension but couldn't get it to work.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: As shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) you need to declare externally_connectable in your manifest. If you already did that, edit the question accordingly. Also make sure you've clicked the reload icon in chrome://extensions page, and reloaded the web page. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for sharing the last link, turned out I checked the wrong console all the time, the message was sent from the website to the extension.